# CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent in swift

Tags: swift

Trying to figure out how to call `CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent` from swift.

It looks like it's been removed from the docs:

Old docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

New docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html

No word on what to replace it with. Anyone know another way to create a scroll wheel event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Swift devs, [C variadic functions are not compatible with Swift variadics](https://devforums.apple.com/message/983462#983462), so you won't be able to call it directly. The only workaround at this time is to write a non-variadic wrapper in C or Obj-C, and call that from Swift.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer + source. Wish they would have reimplemented the same function without the variadic, seems strange to leave it out.